# PHP decode base 64 data into jpeg to view in web browser

Tags: php, ios, swift, post

from my iOS app, I create a POST request with a base64 encoded jpg image like so

```
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)

    if(imageData == nil ) { return }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"\(self.ip)")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")


    let base64Encoded = imageData!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    let postString = "id=\(self.user.userID)&image=\(base64Encoded)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { ...
```

then, in my PHP file I have

```
$imgData = base64_decode($_POST["image"]);

if(file_put_contents('image.jpg', $imgData)) {
  echo json_encode([
    "message" => "The file has been uploaded.",
    "status" => "success",
    "id" => $id
  ]);
}
else {
  echo json_encode([
    "message" => "The file has failed uploading.",
    "status" => "error",
    "id" => $id
  ]);
}
```

The PHP file says that it has all uploaded correctly, but when I go to the url of image.jpg, it does not show an image, just a question mark.

Is the image really there? I can see the file size of image.jpg changing but I cannot view the image. Thank you!

Comment: did you log imgData var to check if it has content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var base64Encoded = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
base64Encoded = base64Encoded.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-._~"))!
```

Comment: @BL Base-64 encoding produces characters like +/=, which you must URL(percent) encode before sending it.